# Passing variable into highcharts solid gauge

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

I have a simple example below that I'm generating in a scriptlet.  How do I pass my variable "z" into the highcharts code below to generate the chart?  Does the data in the scriptlet need to be inside a  ?  Thanks.

```
          <%

            double z = 0;
            z = (73.56/100)*100;

          %>

<script>

var chartRpm = Highcharts.chart('container-rpm', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    title: {
        text: 'RPM'
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'RPM',
    data: [1],
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
               '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
    }
  }]

}));

   // Bring life to the dials
setInterval(function () {
   // Speed
var point,
    newVal,
    inc;

if (chartSpeed) {
    point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0];
    inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
    newVal = point.y + inc;

    if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
        newVal = point.y - inc;
    }

    point.update(newVal);
}

// RPM
if (chartRpm) {
    point = chartRpm.series[0].points[0];
    inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
    newVal = point.y + inc;

    if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
        newVal = point.y - inc;
    }

    point.update(newVal);
  }
 }, 2000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass variable from scriplet code to js code, you can use the following syntax:

```
<%
  double someVar = 0;
%>

<script>
  var someVarFromJSP = <%= someVar %>
</script>
```

So, to use your `z` variable as data for a gauge chart, you have to modify its configuration in the following way:

```
var chartRpm = Highcharts.chart('container-rpm', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    title: {
        text: 'RPM'
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'RPM',
    data: [<%= z %>],
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
               '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
    }
  }]

}));
```